# Powershell - Extract Section from Word Doc

Tags: powershell

Using Powershell, we successfully extracted lines based on pattern

```
get-content "C:\Search.doc" | 
select-string -pattern "means the aggregate of the Facility" a
```

But how can we extract a SECTION from word doc. See example below (we need extract point (a) and (b) which comes under PURPOSE section:

```
3.  PURPOSE
3.1 Purpose
(a) Each Borrower shall apply all amounts borrowed by it under Facility A:
(i) payment to the Vendor of the purchase price for the [xxxx] under the Acquisition Agreement; 
(b) [Each Borrower shall apply all amounts borrowed by it under the Revolving Facility towards the general corporate
```

Comment: Look at the `-*Context` arguments on `Select-String` and use `| Get-Member` on the resulting object.

Comment: am... either I do not get something or You are trying to open .doc as if it was a text file. And it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the property `-Context`:

> Captures the specified number of lines before and after the line with the match. This allows you to view the match in context.

Example:

```
$F = Select-String -Path "audit.log" -Pattern "logon failed" -Context 2, 3
```

The first command searches the Audit.Log file for the phrase "logon failed." It uses the Context parameter to capture 2 lines before the match and 3 lines after the match.

In your case:

```
3.  PURPOSE
3.1 Purpose
(a) Each Borrower shall apply all amounts borrowed by it under Facility A:
(i) payment to the Vendor of the purchase price for the [xxxx] under the Acquisition Agreement; 
(b) [Each Borrower shall apply all amounts borrowed by it under the Revolving Facility towards the general corporate 

Select-String -Pattern "under Facility A" -Context 0,2
```